# Complexity/Operation count for the forward and backward substitution in the LU decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, lu-decomposition

If I have a linear system of equations $Ax=b$ where $A \in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}, x \in \mathbb{R} ^{n}, b \in \mathbb{R} ^{n} $ this system can be solved for $x$ via an LU decomposition: $$A = LU$$ where $U \in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$ is upper triangular and $L \in \mathbb{R} ^{n\times n}$ is lower triangular.

I understand a forward substitution is then required where one first solves:

$$Ly=b$$ for $y$.

And then we solve:
$$Ux=y$$ for $x$.

I am currently trying to determine the *operation count* or the FLOPS for each of the forward substitution and backward substitution. I have seen that the correct value is approximately given by $\mathcal{O}(n^{2})$ flops but I am unsure how one can arrive at this value.

I can see that for the backward substitution, for example, the system is represented as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12}  & \cdots   & u_{1n} \\ 
0 & u_{22} &\cdots  &u_{2n} \\ 
 \cdots&  \cdots & \ddots  &\vdots  \\ 
0 &  0 & \cdots & u_{nn}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1}\\ 
x_{2}\\ 
\vdots \\ 
x_{n}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\ 
y_{2}\\ 
\vdots \\ 
y_{n}
\end{bmatrix}$$

From which:

$$x_{i} = \frac{1}{u_{ii}} \left ( y_{i} - \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}u_{ij}x_{j} \right ); i = n, ..., 1$$

From an equation like this, how can one identify the approximate operation count?

Answer (score 6):

If your matrix is $n\times n$ you have the following operations

1. $n$ divisions,
2. $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ sums,
3. $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ multiplications.

The number of divisions is clear because you have $n$ rows. The number of sums and multiplications are
$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}n^2=\frac{n^2-n}{2}$. It comes from $\sum_{j=1+1}^{n}u_{ij}x_j$.

The total number of operations is $2n^2-n=\mathcal{O}(n^2)$

I hope it solves your doubts

Answer (score 6):

Using your notation for $$x_{i} = \frac{1}{u_{ii}} \left ( y_{i} - \sum_{j=i+1}^{n}u_{ij}x_{j} \right ),$$ for every $i=1,\ldots,n$, we have 1 division, 1 subtraction, $n-i$ multiplications and $n-i-1$ additions (because we have $n-i$ terms in the sum over $j$). Summing up on $i$ gives$$\sum_{i=1}^n 1+1+(n-i)+(n-i-1)=n+2n^2-n(1+n)=n^2 \text{ flops}.$$